# json and content type pyhton flask

Tags: python, json, flask, server, request

I need to transfer to my server side the email password and full_name values filled in by the user.

Despite the fact that I made it clear in my application

```
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
```

I always get the error Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Here is the server-side code

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    data = request.get_json()  
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')
    full_name = data.get('full_name')
    print(email +   password + full_name)
    try:
        if not email or not isinstance(email, str):
            raise ValueError("Invalid Email. Email must be a non-empty string.")

        user = auth.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password
        )
        db = firestore.client()
        user_ref = db.collection('users').document(user.uid)
        user_data = {
            'email': email,
            'full_name': full_name,
            'last_login': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
        }
        user_ref.set(user_data)

        session['email'] = email

        return jsonify({'message': 'User registered successfully'}), 200
    except auth.EmailAlreadyExistsError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Email already exists'}), 400
    except ValueError as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400
```

and here is the client-side code:

```
 function getUserInput() {
    // Get all our input fields
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;

    // Validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) === false || validate_password(password) === false) {
        alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!');
        return null;  // Return null to indicate validation failure
    }
    if (validate_field(full_name) === false) {
        alert('One or More Extra Fields is Outta Line!!');
        return null;  // Return null to indicate validation failure
    }

    return {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        full_name: full_name,
    };
}

function registerUser(userInput) {
    if (userInput === null) {
        // Validation failed, exit the registration process
        return;
    }

    // Move on with Auth
    fetch('/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userInput),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Handle success
        alert(data.message);
        redirectToGoogle();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
        alert('Error registering user: ' + error.message);
    });
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help

I change the content type of my request, I add the CORS option

Comment: "Method not allowed" has nothing to do with the content type. It's about the method.

Comment: Also got the Unsupported Media Type error 
Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.

Comment: I think that's a secondary effect. Since the request is blocked, it's not getting the expected response. You need to figure out why the server is blocking the request instead of routing it to Flaskj.